# How can install specific version of ansible?

Tags: fedora, yum, ansible, pip, virtualenv

How can I install a specific version of Ansible, using Yum or another method?

When I try to install version *2.0* it says *No package 2.0 available*.

I checked the epel repo. There are only two rpms, but no rpm containing version 2.0. Why are they removed? Is there any way to install a specific version of ansible, like 2.0?

Comment: Use the source, Luke!

Comment: yum list|grep -i ansible did output ansible.noarch  2.1.2.0-1.el7  in epel repo

Comment: yes   "ansible.noarch  2.1.2.0-1.el6  epel"

Comment: I recall a co-worker recently handled an Ansible upgrade—you should know that it's only recently that Ansible became available via RPM.  Prior to that it was only available as a tarball.  I *believe* that was version 2.0 that we were upgrading from.  In other words, I don't think there ever was an RPM for Ansible 2.0.  (I haven't researched the matter myself, though.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would recommend `pip`:

```
sudo pip install 'ansible==2.0.0.1'
```

More information on ansible[[1]](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html#installing-and-upgrading-ansible-with-pip) and pip[[2]](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) documentation.

And if you want to have more than one installed version, just use create [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/):

```
virtualenv .env
source .env/bin/activate
pip install 'ansible==2.2.0.0'
```

and only this terminal will use this specific version of Ansible. Then repeat the process for each combination you want.

Comment: ansible=2.0.0.1 should be ansible==2.0.0.1

Comment: This doesn't work. 
After running those 3 steps I ran `ansible --version` in the exact same terminal and environment and it was still running my old version.

Comment: @Snowcrash which version are you trying to install and which version are you getting instead?